# Neither of ---their books or his book

Tags: grammar

> 1. Neither of the twin brothers took **their** books.
> 2. Neither of the twin brothers took **his** book.

Which is most suitable?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you mean *neither brother took his **own** book*. In this case, *his book* is the correct usage. *Their books* is idiomatic and should be avoided.

*Neither of the twin brothers took their books* would be correct if the books were jointly owned, but it requires some context to make this clear. If this were the case, it would be better to say *neither of the twin brothers took **the** books*.

Confusion arises because people wrongly assume that the indefinite pronoun *neither* is plural, and so the error is made.

Comment: I've struggled a bit with this. Hopefully, I've got it right.

Comment: Presumably, if the twins were brother and sister, one would have to say: "Neither of the twins took their books".